# why Try block is retuning SyntaxError before executing except block in Python3?

Tags: python, syntax-error, backslash, try-except

Here I am trying to print "Invalid text" when the string contains Backslash " \ ". I know that in Python strings, the backslash " \ " is a special character called the "escape" character. But when python tries to read the variable s, it returns SyntaxError.

```
try:
     s = '\'
except:
    print("Invalid text")
```

output is

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\pythonProject19\main.py", line 4
    raise SyntaxError if s = '\':
                              ^
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of `\`, your code should be as the following.

```py
try:
     s == '\\'
except:
    print("Invalid text")
```

---

Read more about *Python Escape Characters* here : https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp

Answer (score 1):

You have an unterminated string literal.The proper way to terminate a string literal as is described by you in this instance is `s == '\\'`.